# Alter ajaxified webform confirmation

Tags: ajax, webforms

I manage this website wich was built by somebody else. The client wants me to implement some google tracking codes on several webform confirmation pages.
These webforms call the confirmation message using ajax.
The webform has the redirect settings set to: stay on the same page and the webform is made availible as block.

Normally (without ajax) I would just make a new tpl using this naming format: webform-confirmation-[nid].tpl.php , but that doesn't seem to work because of the usage of ajax.
I have also tried to put the tracking codes inside the confirmation message textarea in the webform backend. but then the message didn't load at all.

So I guess my question is how do I get the ajax to grab my custom template?